# Symantec Corporate Antivirus 7.5 - 4.5 gigs of files?

Tags: windows, symantec

I've got Symantec Antivirus 7.5 Corporate Edition forced on me at work. I notice that it has 4.5 gigs of files here:

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Symantec\Symantec AntiVirus Corporate Edition\7.5

The files are named:
00000A45
00000A48

etc...

Are these safe to delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safer to lower the cache value.. its in Control Panel -> Live Update

Comment: Any idea why this solution may not make the files disappear?  My [question](http://superuser.com/questions/174873/symantec-anti-virus-is-filling-up-my-harddrive) is the same, but isn't solved by this... the files are still around after clearing the cache and lowering the limit... there are 27 of these files and they go back for more than 1 year.

Comment: Well, I've deleted them before, with no adverse side-effects, if they were actually in use surely they would prevent you from removing them, but they aren't.. I think its an archive.. don't know why, who would ever want to roll back definitions?
You should see the SEP Manager.. it filled a 100GB drive!

Comment: @Grizly - you'd be surprised, we had to roll back our McAfee defintions as they released one with false positives around the time of Conficker. We had more problems with McAfee false positives than Conficker and had to roll back our definitions to stop the reboot loop's we were getting...