# Symantec anti-virus is filling up my harddrive

Tags: windows, disk-space, symantec

I've been tracking down where all my disk space is being used and I found out that this folder:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\
Application Data\Symantec\Symantec AntiVirus Corporate Edition\7.5
```

Is taking up 28 gigs (on my only 80 gig harddrive).  The files taking up all that space are 500MB - 1500MB files called things like:  00000074, 0000007A, 000000D8. There are 27 of these files and they go back for more than 1 year.

My question is identical to this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/112879/symantec-corporate-antivirus-7-5-4-5-gigs-of-files), but the selected answer doesn't work for me. After lowering the cache limit from 1800MB to 500MB and clicking to clear the cache, the files are still there, so the answer didn't work for me.

Could this be caused by killing virus scans early?  I don't have permission to kill the process, but my computer becomes useless while its scanning, so I always restart.

Comment: Nowadays, antivirus/spyware/malware software are are becoming almost an equally great an annoyance as the thing they're "defending" us from.

Comment: @Idigas; I say worse, if I restore from a backup the antivirus doesn't go away!

Comment: <tinfoil_hat>What's the business case for actually *stopping* virii?  These guys have a vested interest in keeping users scared.</tinfoil_hat>  Seriously: virtualize; rebuild early and often; practice safe browsing!

Comment: Remove SAV. There are several better and free antivirus solutions today. http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, SAV Corp 7.5 is pretty much useless these days, it will miss A LOT of viruses, even with up-to-date defs. :)

Regardless of that, those are going to be definition updates, but probably from a previous version or a failed update, and that's why lowering the cache number doesn't help any (they're disjointed and SAV doesn't know they're there).

You should be able to just delete them.  You may have to do it in Safe Mode.

Perhaps move them someplace else instead of deleting at first, at least if your worried you may need to put them back.   If it works find after a reboot, you're safe to axe them permanently.

Here's some references:

[Here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/can-tmp-and-vdb-files-be-deleted) and [Here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/symantec-antivirus-corporate-edition75-folder-filled-hard-drive).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no longer forced to use Symantec, but in the past, I've been able to simply delete the offending cache files; have you tried that?  Perhaps you could schedule a job to delete files older than 6 months, or whatever, and have it run every day, or at login.

As for the cause; I was never able to determine one, and I won't share my more cynical thoughts.  I choose not to use Symantec, now, though.

---

Edit:  techie007 above is right; those are probably defs, not cache files.

Comment: I am understandably hesitant to do this (this is on my work computer).  If you could find something official that recommends this, I'll go ahead, but the closest I've found is the same as Grizy's answer from the other question which is [this](http://service1.symantec.com/support/ent-security.nsf/854fa02b4f5013678825731a007d06af/3f1a901d98e33d06802574c000446d21?OpenDocument).

Comment: Speaking as a working BOFH ... Don't upset the BOFH.  ;-)  Unfortunately, I have still-larger-Bs above me, and although I don't have to deal with Symantec, I still have to endure and support a ginormous AV package.  I didn't grok from the question that it was your work PC; I probably should have.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: We'll call them the 'definition update cache files'. ;)